# How to store objects in back-end sessions in Django just like Django stores User

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm creating a webapp in Django. I already run through Django tutorials from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/ and part of documentation

I have a question how to store additional data between requests on the server-side.
Django does it really cool with users as follows:

in views.py:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

now in another function you can use the information stored in back-end which is associated via csrf token like this:

in views.py

```
@login_required
def myappformmethod(request):
    user = request.user
    msg = 'hello '+user.username
```

the generated html file does not contain any direct information about the user which is logged, but it keeps the csrf token as a form field:

```
<form name="myform" action="/myapp/myappformmethod" method="post" onsubmit="prepare()">
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='NwKW2lFWSkkNEasdd3ExHe1l5ltzQi' /></div>
```

I would like to store some session-related data (e.g. favourite color) that will not be visible in html, but will be stored on server side and will be available using something like:

```
if request.favourite_color:
    color = request.favourite_color
```

and not using

```
if request.POST.get('favourite_color'):
    request.POST.get('favourite_color')
```

which is vulnerable to manual form element manipulation (if passed using form fields [type:hidden does not help, since you can edit them as well])

The aproriate approach would be adding field to request and producing something like "login" method mentioned earlier ... but how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: POST data and session data are different. POST data is sent to the server in a POST request, mostly via forms. Session data is stored serverside and is normally identified by a cookie on the clientside, its used to store data between requests, because html requests are stateless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called "sessions" and is supported by Django directly:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

... and here are two examples from that page:

```
request.session['fav_color'] = 'blue'

fav_color = request.session['fav_color']
```